# Continuous deployment to Play Store For Native Application

Tags: android, nativescript, continuous-deployment, circleci

I have got an Nativescript application [CircleCI job](https://circleci.com/gh/rakeshgirase/CloudBuild/84) which basically generates APK file. I want to upload this APK to Google Play store test track. I have seen [Google Publishing API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/#publishing) which can help here. I also saw [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) but I guess it is supported only on iOS devices. Can someone please guide me to good sample where the APK generated are actually published to play store.

I tried searching this on net but couldn’t find helpful blogs which shows end to end deployment of APK's to Google Play store including the authentication and upload. If you are aware about it then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have the apk ready for Play Store release, you can use https://github.com/rakeshgirase/app-release-manager which would help release the apk to the Google Play Store on the specified track.